# How to run tests with code that depends on plugins?

Tags: integration-testing, flutter

I want to test my Firebase data access layer with direct access to Firebase.
Is `flutter drive` the only way to run such tests, or are there other ways like running in emulator using `flutter test`?
What are the possible approaches and how can I set them up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to talk to a real database with `flutter test` currently, because there's no Firebase SDK to do the talking to the network. You probably wouldn't want this anyway, because it could make your tests nondeterministic or flaky if the data changes or the Firebase servers aren't accessible.

Some plugins, like [`shared_preferences`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/shared_preferences/lib/shared_preferences.dart#L132), have an API for providing mock values. You could do something like that for the `firebase_database` plugin, either as a pull request to the first-party repo or by calling `MethodChannel.setMockMethodCallHandler` and `BinaryMessages.handlePlatformMessage` in your test code to simulate what the native side would be doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that this wouldn't work well with unit tests, but I'd like to have a way to run some tests that actually hit the database (don't need to be part of CI). I assume the only way to do this is using `flutter drive` right? Firebase is just the first example I run into. How would it look like with other plugins where testing would actually hit some Android or iOS implementation code? I think this can only run on a device or emulator. Is `flutter drive` the only way to run tests in an emulator, or should this be possible with `flutter test` as well?

Comment: `pub run test` supports platform `android`, but I don't know if this is related to Flutter in any way.

Comment: As far as I know, `flutter test` doesn't run on actual devices.